# Why can't webpack find any module from my React Webapp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I want to run webpack on ubuntu to run my react webapp. When running *webpack* from the command line, I get the following error (just a small extraction of all the errors that I get):

> ERROR in Cannot find module 'loader-utils'  @
>   ./src/components/WaitingMsg.styl 4:14-129 13:2-17:4 14:20-135
>
> ERROR in Cannot find module 'loader-utils'  @
>   ./src/components/CreateBox.styl 4:14-128 13:2-17:4 14:20-134
>
> ERROR in Cannot find module 'loader-utils'  @
>   ./src/components/Trashbin.styl 4:14-127 13:2-17:4 14:20-133
>
> ...
>
> ERROR in ./src/components/Minimap.jsx Module not found: Error: Cannot
>   resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./minimap.styl in
>   /var/www/WebApp/webapp_client/src/components  @
>   ./src/components/Minimap.jsx 23:0-25
>
> ERROR in Cannot find module 'loader-utils'  @
>   ./src/components/IdeaNode.styl 4:14-127 13:2-17:4 14:20-133
>
> ERROR in ./~/react-dnd/lib/DragLayer.js Module not found: Error:
>   Cannot resolve module 'invariant' in
>   /var/www/WebApp/webapp_client/node_modules/react-dnd/lib  @
>   ./~/react-dnd/lib/DragLayer.js 35:17-37
>   ...
>
> ERROR in ./~/socket.io-client/lib/manager.js Module not found: Error:
>   Cannot resolve module 'backo2' in
>   /var/www/WebApp/webapp_client/node_modules/socket.io-client/lib  @
>   ./~/socket.io-client/lib/manager.js 16:14-31
>
> ...
>
> ERROR in ./~/react-dnd/lib/bindConnectorMethod.js Module not found:
>   Error: Cannot resolve module 'disposables' in
>   /var/www/WebApp/webapp_client/node_modules/react-dnd/lib  @
>   ./~/react-dnd/lib/bindConnectorMethod.js 16:19-41
>
> ERROR in ./~/react-dnd/lib/utils/cloneWithRef.js Module not found:
>   Error: Cannot resolve module 'invariant' in
>   /var/www/WebApp/webapp_client/node_modules/react-dnd/lib/utils  @
>   ./~/react-dnd/lib/utils/cloneWithRef.js 8:17-37

I run this on Ubuntu 14.04. What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing any packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you need to install loader-utils into you project. You can do this with the following command.

```
npm i loader-utils --save-dev
```

More info on the package can be found here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/loader-utils

Comment: Also if you have not done so already you should just run the command `npm i` in your project root directory. This will install all packages listed in your `packages.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

It is pointed out that you do not have a module called 'loader-utils'.If you want any help, I'd like to see your configuration of your webpack. I can't help you without more information.