# can't resolve dns/tls when setting up Neo4j

Tags: node.js, webpack, neo4j

I am trying to use `neo4j-driver` in my `node.js` project like that:

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
// neo4j cypher helper module
const USERNAME = "neo4j";
const PASSWORD = "neo4j";
const URI = "bolt://localhost:7687";

const driver = neo4j.driver(URI, neo4j.auth.basic(USERNAME, PASSWORD));
const session = driver.session();
```

When I am running `webpack` it is giving me the following error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal/host-name-resolvers.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in '/home/nikita/Desktop/kipnis_prototype/BrainImmuneConnectome/node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/v1/internal'

And similar errors for `readline`, `tls`, `net`. How could it be solved?

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './views/index.js'
    //vendor: ["react","react-dom"]
  },
  output: {
   filename: 'bundle.js',
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public')
 },
  devtool: "#eval-source-map",
  module: {
   rules: [{
       test: /\.jsx?$/,
       exclude: /node_modules/,
       use: {
           loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory=true',
       }
   }]
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },
  resolve: {
     extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

I know for sure that everything is fine with the database. The error is similar to the following `github` thread:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver/issues/192

However, my importing is right, so I am confused.

> Update

Installing `loader-utils` did not help the issue:
[Why can't webpack find any module from my React Webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425595/why-cant-webpack-find-any-module-from-my-react-webapp?rq=1)

> Update

After supplying the whole path to the `neo4j-driver`:

```
var neo4j_driver = require('../node_modules/neo4j-driver/lib/browser/neo4j-web.min.js');
```

`webpack` runs fine, so I suppose it finds now the driver, however, when I try running the app, another error is shown:

```
Neo4jError: Fatal: No compatible transport available. Need to run on a 
platform with the WebSocket API.
```

> Update

I found out that I can't specify the whole path and that it should be `require("neo4j-driver")` anyway. Then in the following link:

https://github.com/request/request/compare/master...pho3nixf1re:webpack-tests

`externals` section is specified in the `webpack` config file:

```
...
  externals: {
    fs: '{}',
    tls: '{}',
    net: '{}',
    console: '{}'
  }
```

Adding this part to my `webpack.config.js` allowed for running webpack and the app without giving errors in the `node.js` console, however, the browser generates another error in this case that is obviously related to `neo4j-driver`:

[image]

> Update

The previous error in the `Update` above was caused by inappropriate `node.js` modules import, so after fixing that the app started to work like it should be, the question is now solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `externals` section to `webpack.config.js` solved the issue:

```
externals: {
    fs: '{}',
    tls: '{}',
    net: '{}',
    dns: '{}',
    readline: '{}'
  }
```